# Using jqcloud and highcharts

Tags: jquery

I have been using jqcloud and highcharts.
When i load jqcloud after loading highcharts graphs it takes more time, than loading it before highcharts. Is there any specific reason or my code has loop hole.

Comment: how about you show us what you did in code?

Comment: I got it fixed, it was an issue in word cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was calculating offset width, height left and top inside the loop. I calculated it once and passed it as an argument to the hit test function.

The code is available here https://github.com/lucaong/jQCloud/pull/41